# Class Edit View Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to have a class change something on a View Controller without doing `[ViewController alloc]init]`?

I have a separate class calculating several things and I need to change the `scrollView.contentInset` on my `ViewController` as well as some other things.

**Edit for a better explanation:** My `ViewController` contains a scroll view with a text field at the bottom. When the user taps in that text field, I need to change the `contentInset` property of `scrollView`. I want to manage this all using a separate class (instead of having to do this in all of my  View Controllers) so I need to be able to call `scrollView.contentInset` on the `ViewController` that is currently in view.

Comment: Have you taken any thought to global variables?

Comment: This is a bit too vague to answer. Can you expand on your question and post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think of couple ways to handle this:

A.  Using delegate method.
B.  NSNotificationCenter.

Let me know if you need to go into more detail.

Added code as requested:

To use NSNotificationCenter method:

Within the ViewController that has scrollView add an observer statement (perhaps in your viewDidLoad method), and create an method to change whatever property of scrollview you want to change:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethodToChangePropertyOfScrollview) name:@"ChangeScrollView" object:nil];
}

-(void)myMethodToChangePropertyOfScrollview
{
    //scrollView.contentInset = etc...
}
```

From whatever class you want to make the contentInset of that scrollView changed, just post a notification likes this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangeScrollView" object:nil];
```

To use the delegate method, you can use a similar example from one of my previous answer to another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055052/call-a-parent-view-controller-through-a-navigationcontroller/8055480#8055480).  But in your case, I am not 100% sure what are relationship between those two classes.

Comment: Please go into more detail. Keep in mind, I need to change a property on my `scrollView` in my `ViewController` from a completely separate class.

Answer (score 0):

If Mystery Object X needs a reference to a scrollview so it can send it a message, then you need to explicitly provide that reference in.  In Mystery Object X's .h file, declare a @property for the scrollview.  When you create MOX, set the scrollview property.  Now MOX has the reference it needs.

Comment: So my `ViewController` has a `scrollView`. I can only declare a `@property` and use it if I call `[ViewController alloc]init]`from the remote class, which would not work correctly because the view would already be displayed.