# iOS popovers as menu tutorial

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am writing an iPad app and am very new to objective C. I am currently trying to use a popover as a menu within a view controller. I understand how to set the popup up and have a tableview in it for a user to select an item from. However, I am not sure how to then pass the information back to the container view which holds the popover. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will be called within the `UITableViewController` which is presumably inside the popover view controller. Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to get this information back to the container?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're new to iOS, check out this excellent iOS 5 free course in iTunesU from Stanford University.

CS193P: iPad and iPhone App Development (Fall 2011):  http://news.stanford.edu/news/2011/november/itunes-apps-class-111511.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delegate.  It is very commonly used pattern in this situation.  I have an answer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055052/call-a-parent-view-controller-through-a-navigationcontroller/8055480#8055480) similar question with an example.  Let me know if you still are not clear afterward.

Comment: If you need a tutorial on UIPopover, check this out:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Well, I assume that the delegate of your `UIPopoverController` is your content view, if so, you can request the `parentViewController` property from the `UITableView` and then cast it to a `UIPopoverController` to get it's delegate (in your case the delegate would be the container view).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for the answer to this problem. I did solve it using NSNotification.

Here's how:

The View Controller that displays the popup should register to receive the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(languageSetup) name:SPVWChangeLanguage object:nil];
```

// languageSetup is the function that will be called, `SPVWChangeLanguage` is a string that you will define in your popup view controller

I added this line in `viewDidAppear`

Now in your popup view controller add this line when the user selects something in the table:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification: [NSNotification notificationWithName: SPVWChangeLanguage object:self]];
```

before dismissing the popup:

```
[self.popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

That's all. The selector `languageSetup` (in my case) will be called. Be sure to remove the notification when your view controller goes away:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

I do it in `viewWillDisappear`

I think there must be an easier way. But at least, this one works for me.