# Unable to pass value back to parentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have masterViewController and detailViewController. Masterview pushes detailView. When going back to masteViewController I want to update the foo value. But I only get NULL from nslog. How can I set the parenteViewContrller.foo value to @"bar" when navigationback?

masterViewController.h

```
    NSString *foo; 
    -(void)setFoo:(NSString *)fooValue
    @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *foo;
```

masterViewController.m

```
@synthesize foo;

-(void)setFoo:(NSString *)fooValue{

    NSLog(@"updated foo:%@", fooValue);
}
```

detailViewController.m

```
-(void)goBack{
    [self.navigationController.parentViewController setValue:@"bar" forKey:@"foo"];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[UIViewController parentViewController]` will not return what you are expecting from iOS 5 onward, instead you should be using `[UIViewController presentingViewController]`

If you are just targeting iOS 5, it is easy enough to start using `presentingViewController` instead, but if not I would advise that you manually pass your `UIViewController` on:

```
// DetailViewController.h

@class MasterViewController;

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (assign, nonatomic) MasterViewController *masterViewController;

@end


// DetailViewController.m

#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)goBack {

    [self.masterViewController setFoo:@"bar"];

    // dismiss this view controller
}

@end


// MasterViewController.h

@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController

- (void)setFoo:(NSString *)bar;

@end


// MasterViewController.m

#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)goForward {

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = ...;
    [detailViewController setMasterViewController:self];

    // present this view controller
}

@end
```

Comment: Would you suggest saving the UIVIewController in AppDelegate for a global solution?

Comment: @Odelya I would always advise that you avoid clogging up your app delegate with application-wide variables. Better to use singleton instances or some form of manager class.

Answer (score 0):

In order for setValue:ForKey: to work, your view controller must conform to  [NSKeyValueCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

Try this:

```
-(void)goBack{
    [self.navigationController.parentViewController setFoo:@"bar"];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and don't forget to retain/release appropriately in your `setFoo:` method. You probably also need to type cast parentViewController to avoid any warnings.

Comment: This won't work in iOS 5, `[UIViewController parentViewController]` has a different meaning in iOS 5 so you should use `[UIViewController presentingViewController]` if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the reference of the master with assign property to detail view.
Using this reference set the foo value before performing pop action.

Answer (score 0):

gIf you want to pass a object to the parent you could try creating an external object in a header file and importing the header in the controller where you want to use it however THIS IS NOT BEST PRACTICE but it's a quick fix
import

```
extern MyObject* Object;
@interface GlobalVariables : NSObject {

}

@end
```

All you have to do now is include the header in the controllers and use the global variable.

If you want to do it by the books i suggest you create a delegate that handles the object passing.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, under this scenario, you need to use delegate.  Check out my answer to this similar question in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055052/call-a-parent-view-controller-through-a-navigationcontroller/8055480#8055480).