# How to make a callback from a UITableViewController to another UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

I followed this discussion: [UITableView issue when using separate delegate/dataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254354/uitableview-issue-when-using-separate-delegate-datasource), and even though I found it super informative and useful, I have a follow up question:

So I've got a similar setup where I have a UITableView within the UIView. The UIView is controlled by it's own UIViewController (let's call it MyUIViewController) and also I moved the delegate and datasource for the UITableView into a separate subclass of UITableViewController (say, MyUITableViewController).

Everything works fine with the tableView.

The question is, how do I make a callback from MyUITableViewController to the MyUIViewController? For example, if the user selects a cell under the tableView which triggers *didSelectRowAtIndexPath*, I need to update something on the UIView which is actually a parent of this UITableView. So I basically need to send a message to MyUITableViewController. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a delegate pattern in this case.  I have a similar answer with sample code in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055052/call-a-parent-view-controller-through-a-navigationcontroller/8055480#8055480)   .  In your case, the parent view controller is MyUIViewController.  And the child view controller is MyUITableViewController.