# Updating a BOOL value from another class

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, boolean, implicit-conversion

I have setup a class with the following:
MESSidePanelViewControllerSubClass
Header file

```
@property BOOL setLandscapeOK;
```

Imp file

```
- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    // Restriction for the welcome page to only allow potrait orientation

    if (setLandscapeOK == YES) {
        NSLog(@"Reveal-setting all");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    NSLog(@"Reveal-setting portrait");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I now want to update the value from another file (view controller).
LoginViewController
Other view controller imp file

```
- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    // Restriction for the welcome page to only allow potrait orientation
    NSLog(@"Login-supportInterfaceOrientations");
    MESSidePanelViewControllerSubClass* setLandscapeOK = YES;
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

I get an error:

```
Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'MESSidePanelViewControllerSubClass *' is disallowed with ARC
```

How should I be updated the BOOL value in another file?

Comment: Perhaps you need to do a little bit more reading on [what properties and instances](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) are. This is really... weird (assigning a BOOL to an instance of a class named the same as a property of that class)

Comment: instead of `if (setLandscapeOK == YES)`, use `if (self.setLandscapeOK)`. You don't need to compare a `BOOL` to `YES`/`NO`.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
MESSidePanelViewControllerSubClass* setLandscapeOK = YES;
```

It should be something like this:  (Also mESSidePanelViewControllerSubClass is probably an iVar and instantiated somewhere outside your supportedInterfaceOrientations method.)

```
 MESSidePanelViewControllerSubClass *mESSidePanelViewControllerSubClass = [MESSidePanelViewControllerSubClass alloc] init];
```

then:

```
mESSidePanelViewControllerSubClass.setLandscapeOK = YES;
```

Edited to add link to [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055052/call-a-parent-view-controller-through-a-navigationcontroller).

Comment: Would this not create another instance of the subclass though? These are the steps. Welcome view controller created / Nav controller created / Subclass Reveal side panel created and has nav controller as the presented. Welcome should be portrait only. Login view controller is loaded via a button. The login is pushed to the nav controller, which is still held within the Reveal Side Panel (loaded with sub class). The login should be landscape only. I think the above creates a new instance of the sub class as opposed to updating the one already created?

Comment: From what you described, there are several options: A.  Use a delegate pattern.  B.  Passing the reference of the BOOL var.  C.  Use NSNotification.  But using delegate is best choice in my opion for this type acitivies ( see my edited answer with a link to one of my previous answers on this subject.)

Comment: set the delegate on the presenting view controller in prepareForSegue (If you're using storyboards, based on the code I see I'm fairly certain you are) and make sure your delegate is a weak property on the presenting view controller, never retain a delegate, well... unless you have an amazingly good reason to anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `-supportedInterfaceOrientations` in  `MESSidePanelViewControllerSubClass` always return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`? If an instance of `MESSidePanelViewControllerSubClass` is pushed as a child view controller, won't that force your UI orientation to be portrait? Did you try that?