# Can't use reloadData from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have 2 classes, classA and classB
In classA I have a tableview that works and refreshes on demand. all the delegates and datadource are fine and there's also a property `@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *myTableView;`

I don't want to put `reloadData` in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear of classA. 
I want to fire `[myTable reloadData]` from classB.

Thanks

Comment: One option is to use the delegate method.  Here is an [example][1] for how to.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055052/call-a-parent-view-controller-through-a-navigationcontroller

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use delegates to reload your tableview.

In the class where the tableview is, write this in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"updateLeftTable"
                                              object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(checkRes:) name:@"updateLeftTable" object:nil];
```

Then in the same class implement its function like so:

```
-(void)checkRes:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"updateLeftTable"])
   {
      [_rearTableView reloadData];
   }
}
```

Finally, in the class from where you want to reload your tableview
paste the following line (It's important that this line goes in the method from where you want to reload your tableview):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateLeftTable" object:self];
```

Tell me if you have any problems.

Comment: An explanation would be great

Answer (score 1):

When you call    classA *test = [[classA alloc]init];  , it creates a new object of your class A and it has  nil value for every variables you declare in this class. Thats why your reloaddata is not called becoz your array has nil value for this object which you are using to reload the table.

You have to use delegate to pass the object of from class A to class B. And then try to reload the table from this delegate object.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ClassB.h

    @protocol ClassBDelegate <NSObject>

    -(void)reloadTableView;


    @end

    @property (nonatomic,weak)id<ClassBDelegate>delegate;


    ClassB.m

    -(void)methodForReloadingTableViewInClassA
    {

    [self.delegate reloadTableView];

    }




Class A.h
#import ClassB.h
@interface ClassA : UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDatasource,ClassBDelegate>
{
}

ClassA.m   
-(void)createClassB
{
    ClassB *obj = [[ClassB alloc]init];
    obj.delegate = self;
}

    //delagte method of class B
    -(void)reloadTableView
    {

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
```

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot find protocol declaration for 'ClassBDelegate' `

Comment: have you imported ClassB.h in ClassA.h?

Comment: in which class you are getting this error? if in ClassB then declare protocol at the top of ClassB.h... above everything...

Comment: I'm getting it in classA here: `@interface classA : UIViewController   <UIScrollViewDelegate, ClassBDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {`

Comment: i am not sure waht is causing the problem if you have realy imported Classb in classA.. have to look in the code

Comment: I've just created a new fresh project with your code. I'm still getting the same error. You can find the orignal code with the error here: http://pastebin.com/GEB42nWy

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24831/discussion-between-ivishal-and-sha)

Comment: @Sha There might be a case when looping is being formed. If `Class A` is being imported in `Class B`, and so is `Class B` in `Class A`. If that is the case, declare the protocol in separate file.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should reload it by delegates.

Here your ClassB.h Here u need to add your delegate

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id myDelegate;
```

Here your ClassA.m When u are going to ClassB show his delegate t ClassA

```
ClassB *goNext = [[ClassB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassB" bundle:nil];
goNext.myDelegate = self; // ALL YOUR BASE ARE BELONG TO US!
[self.navigationController pushViewController:goNext animated:YES];
```

Next. When u want to reload your classA tableView use the code like this:

```
if (myDelegate && [myDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(reloadMyTV)]){
        [myDelegate performSelector:@selector(reloadMyTV) withObject:nil];
    }
```

where "reloadMyTV" is method of ClassA:

```
-(void) reloadMyTV {
[myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope I remember delegates good enough ) I wrote it by memory ))
Hope it will help

Comment: An explanation would be great

Answer (score 0):

from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData):

> For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible.

so if your `tableView` is not visible then it won't get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the reloadData method refreshes the data as soon as the method is called. Make sure the data source (array or dictionary or wherever you've saved the values) is changed before you call reloadData.

And you should try reloading the data on the main thread :
[tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

Answer (score 0):

check is your `UITableView` property is valid at the moment you call `reloadData`. `UIViewController` is created by calling `alloc init`, but your view is currently in invalid state. Set breakpoint in reloadData line of code and check is you .tableView == nil?