# IOS: Call method in another controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have two separated classes FirstController and SecondController, created with storyboards. The problem is that I want to call method in SecondController.m, FROM FirstController. For ex. :

**SecondController.m**

```
-(void)myMethod:(CGPoint)pt {...} // It's important that there is a paramterer
```

**FirstController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Call myMethod
 }
```

How to do this in the easiest way?

**Update:**
I want to use notification from 'aBilal17' link:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"updateLeftTable"
                                              object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(checkRes:)     name:@"updateLeftTable" object:nil];
```

(..)

```
-(void)checkRes:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"updateLeftTable"])
   {
      [myMethod ?
    }
}
```

In other class:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateLeftTable" object:self];
```

But now, how to pass my CGPoint argument using this?

Comment: What have you looked at? There are hundreds of questions regarding this sort of thing on stackoverflow.

Comment: Unless you're talking about delegate protocols or notifications, you may wish to introduce more model in your MVC. You generally shouldn't be calling code from other controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSNotification or custom delegate for it.

check my ans on the following link.

[Can't use reloadData from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979308/cant-use-reloaddata-from-another-class/14979404#14979404)

Both options are available on it.

Comment: Thanks! Notifications seems to be the best solution. But how to pass an argument (CGPoint) using it (Let's say that I have exactly the same notification as in your link at this moment)?

Answer (score 0):

To pass CGPoint using NSNotificationCenter, you'll need to use NSValue:

```
NSValue *pointValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:myPoint];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateLeftTable" object:pointValue];
```

In your `checkRes:` method, you can obtain the point with the object property of the passed NSNotification:

```
NSValue *pointValue = (NSValue *)[notification object];
CGPoint myPoint = [pointValue CGPointValue];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Call myMethod
    SecondController *controller = [[SecondController alloc] init];
    [controller myMethod:pt];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
 }
```

The `-release` call is only necessary when you are not using ARC.

Comment: This is wrong. The OP states that he created both controllers in the storyboard. Using alloc init will create a new instance rather than getting the one in the storyboard.