# Dismissing Popover and reload parentViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I m actually new to developing iOS application. I currently developing an iPad application where there is two UIViewController (A and B).
A is my parent view controller and B is my UITableView popover that don cover the entire A.

After a row select at B, i manage to dismissed B but it don reflect changes made to A. 
How do i reload the parent view or is a something like android called the onResume method. 
Or ways to solve this problem.

Please provide me with some pointers, have being stuck for hours. Thanks

Comment: You need to use delegate pattern.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055052/call-a-parent-view-controller-through-a-navigationcontroller/8055480#8055480

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the situation. I would suggest 2 ways:

1. As someone mentioned before, you can make a delegate mechanism so that controller B can call something like `-reloadData` on controller A. This is a tight coupling but can solve your problem.
2. You can post a `NSNotification` from controller B and then listen to it in controller A. In controller B:

   ```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       // Do your logic here

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationWithName:@"SettingsSavedNotification" object:nil];

       // Dismiss B controller
   }
   ```

   And in controller A:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveSettingsSavedNotification:) name:@"SettingsSavedNotification" object:nil];

       // Proceed with controller/view setup
   }

   - (void)didReceiveSettingsSavedNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
   {
       // Reload data here
   }
   ```

   Don't forget to call `-removeObserver:name:object:` on controller A teardown.

Answer (score -1):

Use `– popoverDidClose:` NSPopover class delegate method for update your data, or you may use cocoa binding.

Comment: `NSPopover` isn't the name of a class, and `popoverDidClose:` isn't a real selector.

Comment: NSPopover is a class and popoverDidClose: real selector. My mistake that this this answer for OS X.

Comment: Ah, my bad. That makes sense. Still not an answer for iOS.

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

1) You want to make sure you are the delegate to the UIPopoverController you are using to show your popover view controller "B". See the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Then you'll want to implement one of those methods, e.g.:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    // Reload my view controller "A"
}
```

2) How do you know which row was selected in view controller B? It's possible you're updating some singleton that both view controllers have access to, but a better design pattern might be to create your own protocol and for view controller "A" to conform to it. In that case view controller B should have a `weak` `delegate` property that it sends a message to when the user selects a row. Just look at another class that uses the delegate/protocol pattern to see how it works, you could even look at the .h file of `UIPopoverController` by CMD + clicking the class name, or CMD + Shift + O to the file name.

Answer (score -1):

Cant you just use `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` ?