# Calling method from one Viewcontroller inside another

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Noob question fellas, but I cant get it.

I've got a View Controller that loads in a separate View Controller. I would like to be able on a button press to call a method inside the parent View controller. So here is what i've got

parent VC:

```
   .h
    -(void)callParentMethod;



    .m

    -(void)viewDidLoad{
    self.childVC.parentVC = self;
    }

-(void)callParentMethod{
NSLog(@"Hello?");
}
```

child VC:

```
.h

#import "TheParentViewController.h"

@property (nonatomic, weak) TheParentViewController *parentVC;


.m

-(void)addThis{
[self.parentVC callParentMethod];
}
```

I get no errors, the child VC method `addThis` seems to call the method, but the NSLog is never called.  Any thoughts what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055052/call-a-parent-view-controller-through-a-navigationcontroller/8055480#8055480

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `parentVC` releases because of `weak` reference. Try to use this method.

```
-(void)addThis{
NSLog(@"%@", self.parentVC);
[self.parentVC callParentMethod];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
YourParentVC *parent = (YourParentVC*)[self presentingViewController];

parent.whatever = blah;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your application is, but you should not have to keep a reference to the parent view controller. A UIViewController already has a property called `parentViewController` which you can use in the following way:

```
[self.parentViewController methodToCall];
```

This will call a method on the parent view controller. You may need to cast the object in order to call custom methods

```
[(TheParentController *)self.parentViewController methodToCall];
```

This of course assumes that the child view controller's view is a subview of the parent view controller view. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your parent view controller is allocated.

```
   parentnvc = [ParentViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"somenib" bundle:nil];
```

if parentvc is allocated and initialised and call the method

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property in child view controller say,

```
@class ParentVC;
@property(weak,nonatomic)ParentVC *parentVCreference;
```

and get the reference for the Parent view controller as follows

```
self.parentVCreference=(ParentVC*)self.parentViewController;
```

then you can call any exposed methods from ParentVC as follows

```
[self.parentVCreference parentVCMethod];
```

Note: You need to import header of ParentVC in ChildVC implementation file.