# Passing data between view controllers ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I'm working on an app and I need to pass data between view controllers. I know this is a common question but I couldn't find an answer for my problem : I'm able to pass data from the FirstViewController (`MasterViewController` in my case) to the `SecondViewController` (`SettingsViewController`) but not the reverse. What happens is that I call a method from the FirstViewController in my SecondViewController.m file. This works and it logs the data. But when I quit the SecondViewController (using `[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`) the data is reset.
I tried using other methods to pass data but it didn't work. I'm using this code to pass data:

```
MasterViewController *vc = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];

[vc setPorts:SelectedPorts];
```

I also tried replacing `[vc setPorts:SelectedPorts];` with `vc.selectedCellIndexes = SelectedPorts;` but the same problem occurs.

the `setPorts` method is declared in the FirstViewController.h file and `SelectedPorts` is a variable I declared in SecondViewController.m (it's not nil I checked).

Here's the `setPorts:` in **FirstViewController.m** :

```
- (void) setPorts:(id)selectedPorts {
selectedCellIndexes = selectedPorts;
NSLog(@"selectedCellIndexes : %@", selectedCellIndexes);
}
```

This logs the good value but when I log it in `viewWillAppear` in FirstViewController.m it's reset to the value it has before I called the method from SecondViewController.m.

Just to clarify, if I DON'T quit the **SecondViewController.m**, the data isn't reset.

I did read all your comments, and I really thanks you for your help. for convenience, I used a global variable.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: data is reset as secondViewController and it's iVars are deallocated. you need to create an ivar on the master view controller that will hold the data you are speaking about consistently.

Comment: Could you give me some advice on how I'm supposed to do that please?

Comment: @jrock007 How about you show us how you've tried to declare and implement the delegate protocol?

Comment: What's up @jrock007? 7 persons spent time to write answers. May you keep us updated?

Answer (score 1):

In secondViewController, You create protocol

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol sampleDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)passValue:(id)selectedPorts

@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <sampleDelegate> passDelegate;

@end
```

In viewDidLoad or wherever method as per your need, call method like this,

```
[self.passDelegate passValue:selectedPorts];
```

In FirstViewController.h,

Import the delegate `<sampleDelegate>`,

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<SampleDelegate>

@end
```

In FirstViewController.m,

```
-(void)passValue:(id)selectedPorts
{
    id receivedValues = selectedPorts;
}
```

and set self in your SecondViewController allocation,

```
SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
vc.passDelegate = self;
```

Comment: allocate it in FirstViewController.m ? I need to pass data from SecondViewController not to SecondViewController

Comment: btw I forgot to mention I'm using a storyboard

Comment: Are you need to reverse? secondview to Master view?

Comment: Yes, I need to pass the data back... FROM SecondViewController TO MasterViewController

Comment: you need to create delegate and pass data through delegate method

Comment: I tried that a couple of times, but could you give me some code just in case I did it wrong?

Comment: the passValue method isn't called, maybe because I didn't import the delegate in FirstViewController.h well... How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: import the delegate in your firstViewController and one more important when you create secondviewController, after the allocation put delegate = self. i have edited code. please look.

Comment: I tried using #import <sampleDelegate> and #import "sampleDelegate" but none of them worked (I have errors)

Comment: You have to import like this, @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<sampleDelegate>

Comment: I added that (I get @interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, sampleDelegate>) and I have an error : "cannot find protocol declaration for 'sampleDelegate'. I imported SecondViewController (#import "SettingsViewController.h") and I added that in SettingsViewController.h : a protocol sampleDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)passValue:(id)selectedPorts;

a end

Comment: ok good. now that method is fired or not? or receiving any error?

Comment: I have an error : cannot find protocol declaration for 'sampleDelegate' when I try to import it

Comment: Where you declare the protocol declaration? @protocol sampleDelegate <NSObject>

Comment: Declare proctol in SecondViewController, above the interface declaration

Comment: I added @protocol sampleDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)passValue:(id)selectedPorts;

a end in SettingsViewController.h (the SecondViewController header file)

Comment: All are correct, you missing something, i have edited my answer. please look.

Comment: I think the problem might be that I don't have a UIViewController but a UITableViewController.

Comment: that is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

- You have a list of ports in `MasterViewController` and you expect to use it in the `SettingsViewController`.
- The `MasterViewController` can hold this list and `SettingsViewController` should have an access to it.

#### In `SettingsViewController`, have a `setSelectedPort` method:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id selectedPorts

- (void) setPorts:(id)selectedPorts;
```

The method saves the selected ports list into a property.

#### In `MasterViewController`, call the `SettingsViewController` and give it the list.

```
SettingsViewController *vc = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
[vc setSelectedPorts:yourValue];
```

When the list is modified inside the `SettingsViewController`, the list of ports contained in `MasterViewController` won't move even if you leave the `SettingsViewController`.

Comment: The problem is that the user enters the ports so I can't just call a method to change them

Comment: Not if you save the list instance (reference) into the `SecondViewController`. Then you could do whatever changes you wish on the list. Just save it as a property. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing unusual in the getting result. By doing

```
MasterViewController *vc = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];   
[vc setPorts:SelectedPorts];
```

You are creating a new instance of `MasterViewController` from your `SecondViewController`. This is not the same from which you navigated to the `SecondViewController`. So you wont get the expected result. Since you are setting the ports(`[vc setPorts:SelectedPorts]`) to the newly created instance of the Master.

Instead of creating a new instance,just hold the reference of the `MasterViewController` in `SecondViewController` in a property and assign it before moving to second VC. As a beginner I suggested this way. But **using delegate** is the prefferred way passing data back.

Answer (score 0):

Either use delegate methods to communicate with the master VC from the modal VC, or you could do something like this if you want to retrieive some manipulated objects from the modal VC.

Set the object(s) as properties in the modal view controller's .h-file (so they are public).

Using unwind segues, in the master VC, just do this:

```
-(IBAction)exitModalVC:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue
{
    SomeObject *obj = ((YourModalVC*)segue.sourceViewController).someObject;

    //Do what you want with obj
}
```

EDIT:

This will only work if you are using unwind segue (which is a neat way of dismissing modal VC when using story board)

And you are using this, which is not unwind segues:

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You were creating a new instance of the first view controller from the 2nd view controller not accessing the same instance of the original caller.  That was the reason why while you could see the logs but data were not there when you got back to the original caller - your MasterViewController.

You need to use delegate method.  Check my answer for this [SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055052/call-a-parent-view-controller-through-a-navigationcontroller/8055480#8055480)

Answer (score 0):

This is problem related to object ownership.
Follow the below steps:

As per understanding you want reverse value from "SecondViewController" to "FirstViewController"

Don't create new object of FirstViewController in SecondViewController, it will not work.

1. Create object of "FirstViewController" in "SecondViewController.h" file. 
   @property (nonatomic,strong)  FirstViewController *firstViewController;
2. When you navigate from FirstViewController to SecondViewController, please pass the "self".
   e.g. SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
   vc.firstViewController = self;
3. If you want pass the reverse value to FirstViewController then in SecondViewController.m file.
   [self.firstViewController setPorts:SelectedPorts];
4. And in FirstViewController.m refresh your controls with latest values.

Try above code will defiantly work as per your requirement.

Comment: when I add this in SecondViewController.h I get errors : @property (nonatomic,strong) MasterViewController *masterViewController;
The errors are : "unknown type name MasterViewController" and "property with 'retain (or strong)' attributes must be of object type. MasterViewController is the name of my FirstViewController

Comment: Please import the same (MasterViewController)class in SecondViewController. #import "MasterViewController.h"

Comment: You creating object of MasterViewController thats why you need to import same class. #import "MasterViewController.h"